# Semplify $\det\left(D+M+A\right)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $D$, $M$, $A$, $n\times n$ matrices, with $n\in\mathbb N$. $D$ is a diagonal matrix, $M$ with elements all equal to $k\in\mathbb R$, $A$ is an antisymmetric matrix.

Is possible to calculate
$$\det\left(D+M+A\right)$$
without adding the matrices? This is just my curiosity. I think that, given the particular properties of the matrices involved, maybe there is a simplification of this determinant. Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: There are some inequalities that bound the result, but we cannot give the precise value of the determinant (in terms of the determinants of $M+D$ and $A$) without more information about $A$ and $D$.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for why you think that such a thing might be possible?

Comment: No, as I said in the post, it was just my curiosity. I was adding some matrices before calculate the determinant, and I realized that they were matrices rewritable in this form. So I wondered if there was a simplification for the determinant of their sum.